# How to Hide Bot window/iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, botframework

My team is currently working in a Microsoft Bot Framework project. We are displaying the bot with:

```
<iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YOUR_BOT_ID?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE"></iframe>
```

Our customer is asking about show/hide the bot iframe, is it possible to do using an iframe? I was trying example codes like $('#iFrameId').hidden = !$('#iFrameId').hidden on the click event of the iframe, but It's not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can hide iframe.

For example:

```js
function hideShow() {
  let frame = document.getElementById("f");
  frame.style.visibility = frame.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

```html
<iframe id="f" src="https://wikipedia.org" style="visibility: visible;"></iframe>
<button onclick="hideShow();">Hide/Show</button>
```

UPDATE: (solution 2 from my comment) Click on iframe's border to hide iframe.

```js
let frame = document.getElementById("f");

function hideShow() {
  frame.height = frame.height == "0px" ? "150px" : "0px";
}

frame.addEventListener("click", hideShow);
```

```css
#f {
  border-top: #0c0 20px solid;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="f" src="https://wikipedia.org" height="150px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I didn't clarify, I've tried to add the click event to my iframe, but It didn't work.

Comment: Where exactly did you try to add click event listener?

Comment: In a script section, after the iframe declaration. I want to add that click event to iframe.

Comment: The snippet that you showed me works really good, but I'm trying to add that event to the top of the iframe http://prntscr.com/idohes

Comment: If this blue border with "Chat" is inside iframe(it's content), you need to access iframe's document code. And you can easly do it only if iframe is from the same domain.

Comment: Yes Mike, It's inside iframe, but I can't touch that code because is part of Microsoft Bot Framework

Comment: Since you cannot change `<iframe>` inside, I can suggest 3 solutions:
1) Put `<iframe>` into `<div>` and work with it.
2) Style `<iframe>` with top border and change iframe's height to 0 to make it disappear.
3) Use another embed method: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline

Comment: I added example of solution 2 to my answer. But I recommend to use solution #3 or #1, but they are a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the best solution. Also, I understood the problem about "the same domain"

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is like this:

1. use CSS `visibility:` property:-

   ```
   document.getElementById("frame").style.visibility = "hidden";
   document.getElementById("frame").style.visibility = "visible";
   ```
2. use CSS `display:` property:-

   ```js
       function toggle() {
           var e = document.getElementById('frame');
           if(e.style.display == 'block')
               e.style.display = 'none';
           else
               e.style.display = 'block';
        }
   ```

   ```html
        <button onclick="toggle();">Toggle </button>
        <iframe id="frame" src="https://www.w3schools.com" style="visibility: visible;"></iframe>
   ```

Comment: Thank you Deependra Singh, but I want to have that event added to the iframe. Specifically when the top of the iframe is clicked http://prntscr.com/idohes